# cancel opera 15 auto update

Tags: browser, opera

I had limited bandwidth so I cancel all auto-updates and do it manual on unlimited bandwidth, the problem is that I can't cancel auto-update on opera version 15, and opera help stopped at version 12 ([here](http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.00/en/)) the page said...

> Change auto-update settings

At any time, if you want to change auto-update settings, follow the steps below.

```
From the menu, go to Settings > Preferences > Advanced > Security.
In the "Auto-update" section at the bottom, select one of the following options from the drop-down list:
    Do not check for updates – This option turns off the auto-update mechanism. To ensure that you are using the most up-to-date and secure version of the browser, you will need to manually check for updates.
    Notify me about available updates – This option displays the auto-update dialog whenever a recommended update has been released, or from time to time if you have not yet updated the browser.
    Automatically install updates – This option allows all future updates to occur silently (the same as the "Automatically install updates without notification from now on" setting above)
Click "OK" to save your changes.
```

the problem is there is no " Preferences > Advanced > Security." on opera 15.
there is "Privacy & security" and there is no "auto-update"

> I try "crtl F12, run opera as administrator, search in opera settings" and I just cant find any way to cancel opera auto-update.

I don't even know how to manual check for update... Any help?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. That article is outdated. These instructions with `Settings > Preferences > Advanced > Security` applies to Opera 12.xx but not for newest Opera 15.

Comment: I know that, there is no help articles for opera 15... did you know where i can found help for opera 15

Comment: Haven't tried this but in `Opera Next\<version>` folder of Program files, there's an `opera_autoupdate.exe` file - try renaming or moving it to some other folder

Comment: @ Sathya, thanks.... any other answers... where is opera 15 advanced options?

Comment: I found that in opera 15 there is some thing called "Silent auto updates", but I can't find how to cancel it.... any help

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no such option in current versions of Opera.

However you can disable updates using the trick:
Go to the Opera install folder and rename `opera_autoupdate.exe` to something else (for example `opera_autoupdate.exe.disabled`).

Answer (score 1):

Open a new tab and type `opera:config` as the URL.

In the Quick Find search box type `update`.

You should see a check box called Disable Opera Package AutoUpdate. Tick it. Then click the Save button.

If that doesn't work, try to tinker around with the other options that are displayed regarding Opera's update.

Good luck.

Comment: not working "No matches were found. Can't find what you're looking for? Opera help" :(

Comment: Ouch! I just checked and the above works with Opera 12. I assumed that my Opera was always auto-updating that I have the latest version but it looks like not. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me.

However, this one did:

When Opera asks if you want to update to new version, click 'Yes', and then, when Windows asks if you want to install the update, click 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

A boring idea would be : each time you use operA BROWSER , open task manager>go to Processes>right click Opera.auto update>End process .

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidPostill Can You please specify what precisely is wrong with that answer of Raj? It solves the problem and seems to be sufficiently self contained. In contrast, I cannot understand the content of your comment at all - essentially I only see some boilerplate addendum with missing introduction. So for example I think it is a valid answer. Even though maybe not the most convenient one - but that latter perception can also easily change given slightly different circumstances.

Comment: @levitation It's a temporary fix not a permanent solution so it is better as a comment not an answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill Processes can also be automatically killed using some additional tools or scripting. In that sense the answer needs to be improved, but perhaps is still an answer. Permanently removing the executable from its location does not work always either: during next manual update it is back in its location and surely the user forgets to delete it again. Also it might be that the user wants the auto-update to work most of the time, and wants to kill it only in special cases (during being in poor internet area). So it seems to depend on the situation whether the answer suits somebody.

Comment: I totally agree. It's very simple to do this and then it's updating as needed for security. You could even make a script and simply click to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions I found from [this forum thread](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1833848/disabling-auto-updates-saving-certificates-displaying-full-url-and-grouping-tabs):

> You make a shortcut, right-click it, go in properties and add the --disable-update at the end of the the target field which would look like this:
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe" --disable-update

and

> You can also use an environment variable to make Opera auto-updates stop.
>
> Go to Windows's System / Advanced System Settings, in the Advanced tab click the button to manage the Environment Variables and add one called "OPERA_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLED". Done.